# IntelliJ plugin not showing data on the main Project creation Wizard, instead I need to click next. What can cause this?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am making a plugin for Intellij Idea and I am encountering a problem in the project creation phase.

When I click on my plugin in the Project Creation Wizard "Additional Libraries and Frameworks:" with a big square with "Nothing to show" in the center shows up.
I have to click on the "Next" button in order for my settings to show up.
I do not understand what is causing this. Below my plugin.xml if you need it.

```xml
<!-- Copyright 2000-2023 JetBrains s.r.o. and other contributors. Use of this source code is governed by the Apache 2.0 license that can be found in the LICENSE file. -->
<!-- Plugin Configuration File. Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-configuration-file.html -->

<idea-plugin>

  <!-- Unique id for this plugin. Must stay constant for the life of the plugin. -->
  <id>org.intellij.sdk.project.wizard</id>

  <!-- Text to display as name on Settings | Plugin page -->
  <name>SDK: Project Wizard Demo</name>

  <!-- Product and plugin compatibility requirements -->
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>

  <!-- Text to display as description on Settings | Plugin page -->
  <description>
    <![CDATA[
      Demonstrates working with the Project Wizard.
    ]]>
  </description>
  <change-notes>
    <![CDATA[
      <ul>
        <li><b>2.0.0</b> Convert to Gradle-based plugin</li>
        <li><b>1.0.0</b> Release 2018.3 and earlier.</li>
      </ul>
    ]]>
  </change-notes>

  <!-- Text to display as company information on Settings | Plugin page -->
  <vendor url="https://plugins.jetbrains.com">IntelliJ Platform SDK</vendor>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <moduleType
            id="DEMO_MODULE_TYPE"
            implementationClass="org.intellij.sdk.project.wizard.DemoModuleType"/>
  </extensions>

</idea-plugin>
```

UPDATE:

I managed to make the "Additional Libraries and Frameworks:" section be replaced my my plugin's Wizard Step. However now, when I press "Next", a duplicate shows up.

UPDATE 2:
Here are the Pastebin links to my code:

```
DemoModuleWizardStep.java: https://pastebin.com/tHSw0bbS
DemoModuleType.java: https://pastebin.com/QBh5LkDg
DemoModuleBuilder.java: https://pastebin.com/BBhCMPNd
```

Also, I am editing the IntelliJ IDEA's code found here:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/tree/main/project_wizard

Answer (score 1):

From the information you provided and the pastebin links, let's try to diagnose the issues.

1. **"Nothing to Show" Issue**:
   The "Nothing to Show" issue typically arises when your custom `ModuleWizardStep` is not being initialized properly or returned correctly in your `ModuleBuilder`.
2. **Duplicate Wizard Step**:
   When you say "a duplicate shows up" after clicking "Next", it typically means that your `ModuleBuilder` is returning multiple instances of your custom `ModuleWizardStep`.

Let's tackle the problems:

##### 1. Address the "Nothing to Show" Issue:

Ensure that your `DemoModuleBuilder`'s `getModuleType()` method is returning the correct `ModuleType`. The instance you return from `getModuleType()` should match the instance that is registered in your `plugin.xml`.

In `DemoModuleBuilder.java`:

```java
@Override
public ModuleType<?> getModuleType() {
    return DemoModuleType.getInstance();
}
```

And in `DemoModuleType.java`, ensure your `DemoModuleType` singleton is properly initialized:

```java
public static DemoModuleType getInstance() {
    return (DemoModuleType) ModuleTypeManager.getInstance().findByID(ID);
}
```

##### 2. Address the Duplicate Wizard Step Issue:

Ensure that you're only returning one instance of your `ModuleWizardStep` in the `getCustomOptionsStep()` of your `DemoModuleBuilder`. Any other methods that can return a `ModuleWizardStep` should also be checked to ensure they're not inadvertently adding additional steps.

In `DemoModuleBuilder.java`:

```java
@Override
public ModuleWizardStep[] getCustomOptionsStep(WizardContext context, Disposable parentDisposable) {
    return new ModuleWizardStep[]{
        new DemoModuleWizardStep()
    };
}
```

Make sure that if you override other methods like `createWizardSteps()`, they are not inadvertently adding extra steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am still having a problem however. I am getting this now: ```'getCustomOptionsStep(WizardContext, Disposable)' in 'org.intellij.sdk.project.wizard.DemoModuleBuilder' clashes with 'getCustomOptionsStep(WizardContext, Disposable)' in 'com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractModuleBuilder'; attempting to use incompatible return type```

Comment: I am happy to help ,it is maybe related to method signature you have in your subclass (DemoModuleBuilder) does not match the method signature in its superclass or interface (AbstractModuleBuilder), specifically in terms of return type